# Possible to transfer files in peer to peer with a Cordova app?

Tags: ios, cordova, websocket, webrtc, p2p

I have two devices and I would like to send a text file across one and another. Both are on the same router and I know their IP addresses, but they do not have outside network access (no 3G/LTE and the Wi-Fi router is cut from the outside world.)

It might seem crazy, but think of it as being used in moving vehicles with a Wi-Fi router, but you end up in a 3G/LTE deadzone and I still need to transfer data between devices when the server is unavailable.

Would it be possible to use Web RTC or Web Sockets to do a handshake and transfer a text file Device A <--> Device B?

I've seen httpd plugins and web RTC plugins for video and audio streams, but file transfer seems not as popular.

Any idea, or librairies out there that could do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html) is a native framework that can probably do it. I'm not sure whether Cordova has access to it though.

Comment: Thanks, however no one really made a Cordova plugin yet and I'm not good enough in Obj-C for that. Also, MCF requires user intervention and what I'm looking for is something that runs in the background and not visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exchanging the signaling to set up the call (offer/answer/ICE-candidates).  Browser/apps aren't allowed to talk on arbitrary local network ports.

If you already had a DataChannel over WebRTC connected before you lost internet connectivity, that channel could be used to negotiate additional calls.

It's also possible with some additional apps/config (to enable a local http server and change what is there) and cut-and-paste of text from the browser.

If you can run a local http server on a known IP (or equivalent), you could use that for signaling.

Comment: I like your idea as I have already used a Cordova plugin that creates a local http server and confirm I can get to the root index.html from another device. Do you have an idea on how I can expose a method like "http://<devicea>/getFile" and "http://<devicea>/pushFile" ?  https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd